Как правильно настроить sink?
У меня 2 sink. Почему-то logger.exception выводит traceback в обе sink. Почему так? И можно ли как-то разграничить? Info всегда в один sink, error - в другой.
from loguru import logger
import sys

format_string = "{time} {level} {message}"

logger.add(
    sink=sys.stdout,
    level="INFO",
    format=format_string,
    colorize=True,
    backtrace=False,
    enqueue=False,
)

logger.add(
    sink=sys.stderr,
    level="ERROR",
    format=format_string,
    colorize=True,
    backtrace=True,
    enqueue=False
)

try:
    2 / 0
except Exception:
    logger.exception("axixa")


«Info всегда в один sink» — неа, info и более важные. Error является более важным чем Info и поэтому обязательно попадёт сюда

@andreymal не совсем понял что вы описали

Параметр level устанавливает минимальный уровень выводимых логов. Error имеет имеет более высокий уровень чем Info и поэтому должен выводиться в оба sink'а

@andreymal а как обойти этот момент никак?

На enSO предлагают некий filter использовать (работоспособность не проверял) https://stackoverflow.com/a/77751843
